# How to create open a new image in tkinter without previously saving image to drive?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

Lets say I would like to open a new completely white image in tkinter in Python without already having saved the image to my drive. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You could create the image using PIL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a completely blank image with transparent pixels, just create an instance of `PhotoImage`:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
image = tk.PhotoImage(width=64, height=64)
label = tk.Label(root, image=image)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

If you want it to be white, you can use the `put` method to color all of the pixels:

```
image.put('white', to=(0,0,63,63))
```

Comment: Wow. Where is that `.put` method documented?

Comment: @PM2Ring: it's in the docstring for the `PhotoImage` class. There's also at least one question here on stackoverflow. The canonical tcl/tk documentation is here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/photo.htm. It requires a little mental gymnastics to apply it  to python/tkinter.

Comment: Thanks. I _thought_ I tried calling `help()` on a `tkinter.PhotoImage`, but I bungled it, and looked at the help of a `ImageTk.PhotoImage` instead. :oops: